# How to put an ID from a scala template into an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scala, playframework

I'm using the play framework 2.3.8 and have build an application where you can enter questions and answer them.

My view class gets a `List[Question]` which I run through with a for each loop and show them:

```
@for(question <- questionList){
<!-- Questions -->
<li class="list-group-item" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="upvoteButton" 
value="voteUp" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span>
</button>

<span class="num"> @question.voteScore </span>

(...)
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Example]

Via jQuery you can up- / downvote the QAs, now I want to put the changed voteScore into the DB by using AJAX. The click on the button starts an AJAX POST, that sends my controller the current score and should later also send the questionID:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 'voteUp'){
            $(this).html( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up' aria-hidden='true' style='color:orange'></span>" );
            var currentScore = $(this).parent('li').find('.num').text();
            $(this).parent('li').find('.num').html(parseInt(currentScore) + 1);

    $.ajax({ 
        type : 'POST',
        url : '@routes.Application.voteUp()',
        data : {
            text : currentScore
        },
        success : function(data){
        }
        });
    });
});
```

But I dont know how to get the questionID into the AJAX POST, `id : @question.questionID` in the data part of the AJAX POST does not work (value not found error). How do I manage to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First provide attributes to store Question ID:

```
<span class="num" id="@question.questionID"> @question.voteScore </span>
```

Second provide JS variable to store ID from selected question:

```
var currentId = $(this).parent('li').find('.num').attr('id');
```

Third send it to controller as JSON via Ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type : 'POST',
        url : '@routes.Application.voteUp()',
        data : {
            score : currentScore, id_question : currentId
        },
        success : function(data){
        }
        });
    });
```

The last, get it both score and id_question from Controller.

Comment: Really good idea to use the ID field, this also helps me understand how to mix AJAX and the Scala templates. This also makes my generated HTML nicer, as now all QAs have an ID.